# swift connection to mysql in macos

Tags: mysql, swift, xcode, macos

I was wondering if anyone use the project MySqlSwiftNative (https://github.com/mcorega/MySqlSwiftNative) to make their inserts, updates, and queries in MacOS using Swift? I've tries others but I can't get them to work in a project. I can do inserts and updates just fine. The problem I have is pulling the data.
I have tried using its various classes to do the pulls as well as just sending a raw sql query. I can get it to query the data but all I get is something like the following:

```
Optional([[["emppayrate": 10.0, "empnumb": 1, "praterecordnumb": 1, "empdatepaybegin": 2018-11-01 04:00:00 +0000], ["emppayrate": 8.0, "empnumb": 2, "praterecordnumb": 2, "empdatepaybegin": 2018-10-22 04:00:00 +0000]]])
```

Since I am using this query to fill in fields and variables in my application what I'd like to do is something like this...

```
let res = try con.query("SELECT * FROM prate")
           let rows = try res.readAllRows()
var column1 = rows.column("column1")
var column2 = rows.column("column2")
```

i know this isn't the exact syntax but you get the idea. i am so stuck on this.

Comment: You need to be a little more precise in your question, "something like" and "isn't the exact syntax" isn't very helpful. Try to create an example of what your code and query is, what your result was and what you expected instead.

Comment: as what i am trying to do seemingly doesnt exist...i cant be more precise. the results in the post are what comes back from the let rows = try.readAllRows(). So i know it is bringing the data back from the query. What I cannot figure out is how to assign specific columns from the row into a variable or an outlet that is connected to the interface.

Comment: I still don’t understand why you can’t give a proper example, you have obviously code that executes.

Comment: let res = try con.query("SELECT * FROM prate")
let rows = try res.readAllRows()
print(rows)

Executes fine. It brings back 
Optional([[["emppayrate": 10.0, "empnumb": 1, "praterecordnumb": 1, "empdatepaybegin": 2018-11-01 04:00:00 +0000], ["emppayrate": 8.0, "empnumb": 2, "praterecordnumb": 2, "empdatepaybegin": 2018-10-22 04:00:00 +0000]]])
as a result. So I know the query works. But i can't figure out how to get the columns of each row to map to a variable or directly to an outlet. The driver doesn't seem to be able to. It should be like
var column1 = row["column1" as Int

Comment: Possibily instead of how to make it work maybe the best way to process the json(?) that it is returning?